# How to control the return from a function using signal slots in qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I am requesting a json object from an API. I am using signal  slots for reading the reply and then converting reply to json object. Till here everything is ok

but problem starts when I want to give output I am using a class member to give the ouput but class member is getting update at later time and function return the class member initial value.

My question is how to make sure that value is update before it returns. 
I have tried QTimer but does not solve problem.

```
qint64 RestApiFetcher::totalSize()
{
    request->setUrl(m_ipaddr + "?$count=true" + m_strtop);
    IgnoreSSLCertification();
    mNetReply = mNetManager->get(*request);
    connect(mNetReply,&QIODevice::readyRead,this,&RestApiFetcher::dataReadSize);
    connect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,this,&RestApiFetcher::dataReadSizeFinished);

    qDebug() << m_totalSize;

 return m_totalSize;
}

void RestApiFetcher::dataReadSizeFinished()
{
    if( mNetReply->error()){
        qDebug() << "There was some error : " << mNetReply->errorString();
    }else{

        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(*mDataBuffer);

        QJsonObject data = doc.object();
        m_totalSize = data["count"].toInt();
    }

    qDebug() << "#############";
    qDebug() << m_totalSize;
}
```

and the output is

```
0
#############
150
```

What I need is

```
#############
150
150
```

basically the slot should run first and then the function should give output.

**Update**

```
    qint64 RestApiFetcher::totalSize()
    {
        request->setUrl(m_ipaddr + "?$count=true" + m_strtop);
        IgnoreSSLCertification();
        mNetReply = mNetManager->get(*request);
        QEventLoop loop;

       connect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop,&QEventLoop::quit);
       loop.exec(); // waits until `quit` called from signal above
    disconnect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop,&QEventLoop::quit);

        dataReadSizeFinished();
        qDebug() << m_totalSize;

     return m_totalSize;
    }
```

and the output is

```
#############
0
0
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at `QFuture`. It seems suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use a `QEventLoop` to wait for the `finished` to occur. This is what I do if I need to wait on network communication before continuing. This would eliminate the need for `dataReadSizeFinished`, which could then be combined into your `totalSize` function, or just using a simple call to the function instead of through a signal.

```
qint64 RestApiFetcher::totalSize()
{
    request->setUrl(m_ipaddr + "?$count=true" + m_strtop);
    IgnoreSSLCertification();

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop,&QEventLoop::quit);

    mNetReply = mNetManager->get(*request);

    loop.exec(); // waits until `quit` called from signal above
    disconnect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop,&QEventLoop::quit);
    dataReadSize();
    dataReadSizeFinished();

    qDebug() << m_totalSize;

    return m_totalSize;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have used a similar approach i.e.    using Qtimer and loop

Comment: qt compaling of signal and slot argument not compatible. connect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop, SLOT(quit()));

Comment: Don't use `SLOT`, just use `&QEventLoop::quit`

Comment: inside connect and discoonect "this" doesnt work it needs a pointer so i put &loop something like this connect(mNetReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,&loop, &QEventLoop::quit); It is compiling but stilling i am not getting results.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have said `&loop`. Was copying and pasting and missed a part. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Are you using a signal to call `dataReadSizeFinished`? If so, the order of the calls isn't guaranteed and you still end up in a race. If you step through, in the `dataReadSizeFinished`, is `mNetReply` an error? Or does it have anything? I don't know what `dataReadSize` does, but does it set any data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201034/discussion-between-chrismm-and-mandeep).